# Does kubernetes list permissions allow getting individual objects in the collection

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

Does the role below allow getting the contents of all secrets in the `bar` namespace, or just the secret named `foo`? I don't understand what the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb) mean by

> list (for collections, including full object content)

What does "full object content" mean in this context?

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: fooer
  namespace: bar
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: [secrets]
    verbs: [list]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: [secrets]
    verbs: [get, watch]
    resourceNames: ["foo"]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A role is specific to a `namespace`. So the yaml actually should look like

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: role
  namespace: default
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: [secrets]
    verbs: [list]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-binding
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: role
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
```

For collections(secrets for example) `list` means permission on all the resources together coming under the list. Because of that you can get all secrets with the above role using below command

```
kubectl get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default -n default -o yaml
```

but you can not get each secret individually using

```
kubectl get secrets/default-token-bwk2x --as=system:serviceaccount:default:default -n default -o yaml
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "default-token-bwk2x" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

***Including full object content*** means the content of all the objects together coming under that list as you can see using the first command above.

> Does kubernetes list permissions allow getting individual objects in
> the collection

No, It does not. You can only get full aggregated content of all the items in the list but not the content of each item individually.

Comment: even though list is not limited to `foo` and list has `including full object content`?

Comment: i editted the question to also ask what exactly full object content means. that is the root of my question. sorry for not being clear initially. thank you

Comment: Have updated the answer..list gives permission to get all elements but not each individually

Comment: I'm suspicious. this is a security question so I need to be absolutely sure. client-go has a method to list secrets that returns the full object, not just the name. https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes/typed/core/v1#SecretInterface. I understand that kubectl might not be able to.

Comment: I never said it returns only the name..I said it returns full aggregated content in yaml and json format...yes it's a security concern because you can see the content..it's not possible to get individual object content with list permission